# App with integrated SQLite database keeps crashing

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I´m new to android programming and i was trying to make an app with an integrated SQLite database.

After many frustrated tries of writing a code that copies the DB from the assets folder to the internal memory, i stumbled upon this **SQLiteAssetHelper** library and tried to use it, but it just opens the blank app screen and, after some seconds, it crashes and shows the message "(AppName) has stopped."

I´m testing my app in a real device, a non-rooted Samsung Galaxy S3.

Some code:

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.database2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private Cursor employees;
private Database db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

db = new Database(this);
employees = db.getEmployees(); 

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
employees,
new String[] {"name"},
new int[] {android.R.id.text1},0);

getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
employees.close();
db.close();
}


}
```

**SQLite Asset Helper**

```
package com.example.database2;

import android.content.Context;
import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;

public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  
    }



public Cursor getEmployees() {

SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

String [] sqlSelect = {"_id", "name", "number"};
String sqlTables = "contacts.db";

qb.setTables(sqlTables);
Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null,
null, null, null);

c.moveToFirst();
return c;

}



}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.database2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.database2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Glad if someone can help.

EDIT:

I´m posting the relevant logcat, although it doesn´t gave me much information:

**Logcat**

```
E/SQLiteDatabase(3658): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.example.database2/databases/contacts'.
E/SQLiteDatabase(3658): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
E/SQLiteDatabase(3658): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
E/SQLiteDatabase(3658): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:278)
```

Comment: @Ritesh Gune Added the logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, turns out that the problem was simple and stupid: i was just copying my zipped database to the assets folder when it turns out it should be copied in **assets/databases** for SQLiteAssetHelper to work.

After creating the folder and putting the DB in it, everything worked.

Answer (score -1):

could you add the LogCat output why it is crashing?

AND

your database name is contacts.db, not your table name

please set the right tablename in

```
String sqlTables = "your_table_name";
```

EDIT:
I try to give you a brief introduction into using SQLite in Android like i did it in one of my projects.

First you have a DBHandler Class:

```
 public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // table names
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "contacts";

    // table column names
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_NUMBER = "number";

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Statements for creating tables
    private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," + COLUMN_NAME
            + " VARCHAR(255)," + COLUMN_NUMBER + " VARCHAR(255);";

    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Create tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(DBHandler.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Then you need a class that handles your queries and other stuff ... lets call it DataSource:

```
public class DataSource {

// Database fields
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private DBHandler databaseHelper;
private String[] allColumns = { DBHandler.COLUMN_ID,
        DBHandler.COLUMN_NAME, DBHandler.COLUMN_NUMBER};

public DataSource(Context context) {
    databaseHelper = new DBHandler(context);
        this.open();
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    databaseHelper.close();
}

    // here you can place your custom functions 
    public Cursor getEmployees(){
            Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHandler.TABLE_NAME,
            allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor;
    }
}
```

In your MainActivity you do:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

        private Cursor employees;
        private DataSource datasource;
        private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        datasource = new DataSource(this);
        employees = datasource.getEmployees(); 

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        employees,
        new String[] {"name"},
        new int[] {android.R.id.text1},0);

        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        datasource.open();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        datasource.close();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Your layout should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It is important that the id of the ListView is android:list.

I didn't test this particular one but i adjusted my code to this. It should work like that.

Comment: Both my database and the table are called "contacts", but i removed the .db from the table name. Still no changes.

Comment: After doing a little tweaks to your code it worked for me, but it just creates an empty database, i still can´t copy the data from my database in the assets folder.

Comment: you have to fill it with data

Comment: The point is that soon I will need to use a much larger and existing database that will be copied. I already tried some codes that added the data programatically and they worked well, but every time i try to copy existing data my app crashes.